# Qt не создаёт исполняемый файл, qt 5.12, линукс минт 19

Tags: linux, qt5

В общем, всё установил, Qt с оф. сайта, инструкции взял с этого сайта:
http://sergmuskwo.beget.tech/ustanovka-ide-qt-creator-v-linux-mint-19-pamjatka/

Всё работает, за единственным исключением: в самом Qt проект (простой, тестовый, оконное приложение) выполняется нормально, но в папке релиз вместо выполняемого файла создаётся "разделяемая библиотека" - посмотрел в свойствах файла. Что это может быть?

файл .pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2021-01-14T10:34:25
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = kalend
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        widget.cpp

HEADERS  += widget.h

FORMS    += widget.ui
```

Comment: Если вопрос не в установке, поправьте заголовок вопроса, чтобы он соответствовал вопросу.

Comment: разделяемая библиотека не может выполняться сама по себе. если проект компилируется и выполняется, исполняемый файл должен быть. ищите лучше.

Comment: Приведите содержимое `pro` - файла.

Comment: я думаю это потому, что в некоторых случаях выполнимый файл помечается менеджером файлов неверно. То есть, там нормальный бинарь, но автор вопроса читает, что пишет ему менеджер. Плюс ко всему - инструкция ужасная - она рекомендует скачать с сайта Qt, а не пользоваться тем, что уже есть в пакетах.

Comment: Но файл не выполняется. Задаётся вопрос - с помощью какой программы открывать? И устанавливал я qt из репозитория - точно то же самая проблема.

Comment: значит происходит попытка запустить не тот файл

Comment: Сложно работать с ОС, которая запускает не тот файл, по которому кликнул мышкой.

Comment: Что возвращает утилита `file` по вашему файлу?

Comment: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=728869f8086f509d3e69933c44783664d4c7e84a, not stripped

Comment: Из консоли пытались запускать файл на исполнение?

Comment: Попробовал, удивительно, но из консоли запустился. Только вместе с консолью - закрываешь консоль, закрывается и файл. И что это значит? Хотелось бы, что-бы запускался самостоятельно двойным кликом мышки, как все обычные файлы.

Comment: то, что оно с консолью вместе закрывается - это нормально. Это штатное поведение обычных программ. Можно использовать nohup, `&` или вручную отцепится от терминала. Но вот почему не запускается с файлового менеджера... может привязка кривая. а другие программы запускаются так?

Comment: Ну я посмотрел более ранний проект (с другим линуксом и Qt) - там в релизе создан исполняемый файл (он не работает, потому что нет необходимых библиотек, но в свойствах написано исполняемый и иконка другая). А тут иконка как текстовый файл, в свойствах пишет что библиотека, и ессно не запускается - спрашивает, с какой программой запускать. Можно как-то поменять тип файла на исполняемый?

Comment: @alexu007, вам явно следует ознакомится с линуксом поглубже, ну хотя бы базовые вещи, как `rwx`

Comment: @SergeyPavlov, ну и кто вам это сказал? Загрузчик запустить может и библиотеку.

Answer (score 0):

Ну в общем это баг линукс минт - она видит Qt-шный исполняемый файл как библиотеку. Почему - не знаю. Если в файл проекта вставить строчку QMAKE_LFLAGS += -no-pie, то файлы начинают определяться как исполняемые - случайно наткнулся. Но говорят, что так нельзя. Но так работает, а по другому нет.
А как файловый менеджер (или что там в линуксе) определяет тип файла? Расширения нет, говорят, что есть заголовок - может в заголовке какой-нибудь байтик поменять? Или в файле проекта что-нить другое поменять/вставить?

Comment: дополнительные вопросы из ответа лучше убрать и либо перенести их в текст вопроса, либо задать как новые вопросы. чтобы исправить сообщение (вопрос или ответ), нажмите ссылку «править» ниже текста сообщения.